# converting a pdf page to an image using GraphicsMagick

Tags: pdf, jpeg, graphicsmagick

How do I convert only page 2 of a pdf file to a jpg image file, using GraphicsMagick command line prompt?

What option can I use in the gm.exe convert command?

```
gm.exe convert testing.pdf testing.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the page number (starting from zero) in square brackets after the PDF filename:

```
gm.exe convert testing.pdf[1] testing.jpg
```

By the way, you can use the same indexing technique for accessing specific frames of a GIF animation, or layers of multi-layer/directory TIFFs.

Answer (score 0):

use the blow command, will get high quality png with white background.

```
magick convert -density 300 -quality 100%  -background white -alpha remove -alpha off ./646.04.pdf  ./x.png
```